# Save value in reload page javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window, local-storage, onbeforeunload

I want to save data in the input when the page reloading and I don't 
       know why my code doesn't work. This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <label>nom:</label> <input type="text" value=""/></br>
        <label>prenom:</label><input type="text" value=""/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        localStorage.setItem(nom, document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
        localStorage.setItem(prenom, document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value);
            }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
            var nom = localStorage.getItem(nom);
            var prnom = localStorage.getItem(prenom);
            if(nom!==null&&prenom!==null) {                 
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = nom;
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = prenom;
            }
        });

         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code was setting the localStorage values when the page was loaded which means it set it to be no text so the code won't save. Use the code from the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use quotes for the variable name:

```
localStorage.setItem('nom', document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
```

Or you can use this which is simpler:

```
localStorage.nom = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
```

## Your code was setting the localStorage values when the page was loaded which means it set it to be no text so the code won't save.

## Use the below code:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  var nom = localStorage.nom;
  var prnom = localStorage.prenom;
  if (nom !== null && prenom !== null) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = nom;
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = prenom;
  }
};
```

```html
<label>nom:</label> <input type="text" onchange="localStorage.nom = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value" /></br>
<label>prenom:</label><input type="text" onchange=" localStorage.prenom = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value" />
```

## IMPORTANT: use the code on your computer because localStorage doesn't work on stack overflow snippets

Comment: i try it now and this solution doesn't solve the problem :/

Comment: Your code was setting the localStorage values when the page was loaded which means it set it to be no text so the code won't save. Use the code from the snippet.

Comment: thanx  i try now and this fix my problem i set a default value in the input and reload and that s work good
localStorage.nom = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

Comment: Put `localStorage.nom = localStorage.nom || ""` in the `onbeforeunload` function to set a default value if it is `undefined`.

Comment: ok that s good , i went to ask you if you have a solution using angularjs ?